# How can I prevent decimals being rounded when using DecimalFormat?

Tags: java

Can anyone help how can i prevent rounding decimal value.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();

Object[] arrayRowResult = (Object[]) rowResult;
String a=df.format(arrayRowResult[0]) // [0] contain decimal(2,10) but format results rounded value
String b=df.format(arrayRowResult[1]) // [1] contain decimal(2,14) but format results rounded value
```

How can i prevent round off.

Comment: You need to round/truncate the numbers yourself.

Comment: it doesn't round for me - what is the type of rowResult?

Comment: Hi peter,,rowResult is ScrollableResults object..thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
// .... your code
```

This will still round the numbers having more than two fraction digits -- change that value as you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried following?

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
```

Comment: you may need also to set df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.FLOOR

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits(int)

and

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setMinimumFractionDigits(int)

Of course, both methods need that the precision is known a priori (it is not useful if it can have an arbitrary number of decimals).

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.mkyong.test;

import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class TestDouble {

    private static DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".##");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double input = 32.123456;
        System.out.println("double : " + input);
        System.out.println("double (default) : " + df2.format(input));

        df2.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);
        System.out.println("double (UP) : " + df2.format(input));

        df2.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
        System.out.println("double (DOWN) : " + df2.format(input));

    }

}
```

Copy
Output

```
double : 32.123456
double (default) : 32.12
double (UP) : 32.13
double (DOWN) : 32.12
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for your code, and fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);**

```
    double a = 980.199999;
    
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
    String as = df.format(a);
    System.out.println(as);
```

This is will even add 2 decimal point for integers if you don't need you can change  DecimalFormat

Output:
980.19